# NServiceBus and Azure long running handler pattern

Tags: azure, message-queue, nservicebus, azureservicebus

We are using Azure service bus via NServiceBus and I am facing a problem with deciding the correct architecture for dealing with long running tasks as a result of messages.

As is good practice, we don't want to block the message handler from returning by making it wait for long running processes (downloading a large file from a remote server), and actually doing so will cause the lock on the message to be lost with Azure SB. The plan is to respond by spawning a separate task and allow the message handler to return immediately.

However this means that the handler is now immediately available for the next message which will cause another task to be spawned and so on until the message queue is empty. What I'd like is some way to stop taking messages while we are processing (a limited number of) earlier messages. Is there an accepted pattern for this with NServiceBus and Azure Service Bus?

The following is what I'd kind of do if I was programming directly against the Azure SB

```
{
     while(true)
     {
          var message = bus.Next();

          message.Complete();

          // Do long running stuff here 
     }
}
```

The verbs Next and Complete are probably wrong but what happens under Azure is that Next gets a temporary lock on the message so that other consumers can no longer see the message. Then you can decide if you really want to process the message and if so call Complete. That then removes the message from the queue entirely, failing to do so will cause the message to appear back on the queue after a period of time as Azure assumes you crashed. As dirty as this code looks it would achieve my goals (so why not do it?) as my consumer is only going to consume the next time I'm available (after the long running task). Other consumers (other instances) can jump in if necessary.

The problem is that NServiceBus adds a level of abstraction so that now handling a message is via a method on a handler class.

```
void Handle(NewFileMessage message)
{
    // Do work here
}
```

The problem is that Azure does not get the call to message.Complete() until after your work and after the Handle method exits. This is why you need to keep the work short. However if you exit you also signal that you are ready to handle another message. This is my Catch 22

Answer (score 2):

Downloading on a background thread is a good idea. You don't want to to increase lock duration, because that's a symptom, not the problem. Your download can easily get longer than maximum lock duration (5mins) and then you're back to square one.

What you can do is have an orchestrating saga for download. Saga can monitor the download process and when download is completed, b/g process would signal to the saga about completion. If download is never finished, you can have a timeout (or multiple timeouts) to indicate that and have a compensating action or retry, whatever works for your business case.

Documentation on Sagas should get you going: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/

Comment: We are having a go at using sagas and it certainly does help orchestrate the download and follow up actions. However the fundamental problem seems to be that NServiceBus and AzureSB don't plat as nicely together as you'd hope. What happens is that as soon as another start download message hits the bus a new saga is launched. Ideally we just want to stop processing the queue until the first saga is done.

Comment: @naskew are you trying to perform sequential downloads? I.e. if you receive 2 messages, 2nd download should not start until the first one is done?

Comment: It is expected that we will only need to do one download. However it is possible that the other end might send us a request to perform another download and I really just want to ensure that we wait.

My issue here is that people talk about using messaging to load balance. My problem is that using the Handler pattern of NServiceBus it appears that you cannot tell NServiceBus not to send the next message immediately except by not returning from the call. Whereas native Azure supports that.

Comment: I'd disagree about the sending. Sending is not under receiver`s control, both for raw ASB or NSB. The way you throttle message processing using raw ASB can be done with NSB as well. Have a single saga for all downloads, and not per download. When new requests for downloads are coming in while your saga is still handling the previous download, store info about thevrequest and get to it when the previous is either finished or timed out. That way you'll throttle it. Plus, you can decide how many concurrent downloads can take place. If you decide to have more than one, you'll be able to do it.

Comment: Sean, that was my initial thought too. The problem is that this pattern does not work with load levelling across multiple concurrent listeners. You could have multiple Sagas running on multiple VM's as singletons per machine but then the load balancing would depend on which VM was given priority to the incoming messages and not which was least busy. However I do agree that for a single instance your suggestion would work.

Comment: I would design it the following way: allow each instance of your saga to accept incoming download requests and register those as a 'pending download' record in some data store. Then provide each instance with exactly one background thread that reads a pending download record and start downloading & processing the file. Optionally let it send messages to itself for state tracking, so that you can report progress to the user.

Note: if you want to limit the download to just a single instance across all nodes, then you could use a blob lease to determine which of the instances is the active one.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Service Bus you can increase the lock duration of a message (default set to 30 seconds) in case the handling will take a long time.

But, besides you are able to increase your lock duration, it's generally an indication that your handler takes care of to much work which can be divided over different handlers.

Comment: I'd agree with your assertion that the handler is doing too much but being a little more specific, we need to download a very large file from another server. So the task cannot be broken up.

Answer (score 0):

If it is critical that the file is downloaded, I would keep the download operation in the handler. That way if the download fails the message can be handled again and the download can be retried. If however you want to free up the handler instantly to handle more messages, I would suggest that you scale out the workers that perform the download task so that the system can cope with the demand.

Comment: If you do that with Azure SB then Azure will assume you have crashed and put the message back on the queue. Personally I think the match between the process model of Azure SB and NServiceBus are not good and that perhaps when the Async model is up and running in NServiceBus (we are on 5 still) that this will possibly be solved. However it depends how NServiceBus decide to handle de-queuing messages. If they wait until after the async code is complete then I'll still have the same problem.